# slack: how to know who voted with reaction

Tags: python, bots, slack

How can I know who voted with reaction on the slack? I want to create a bot which gets who voted with reaction as an input, and send message based on that information. Any simple codes for it, like with slackclient or slackbot?

Comment: look at the slack API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely want to look at using the Events API (https://api.slack.com/events-api), specifically the `reaction_added` event (https://api.slack.com/events/reaction_added).